# Does Safari 5.1 ignore Access-Control-Allow-Origin * wildcard?

Tags: ajax, cross-domain

Trying to make a cross protocol, same domain request from https to http. I have set the response headers to read `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` which is indeed working in Chrome. However, it doesn't work in Safari.

Is Safari ignoring the wildcard? Is it giving the wrong error and indeed there is a different problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found out that this indeed not the case. Instead what is happening is that Safari is making an OPTIONS call to the server before the AJAX call, and in my case my server framework doesn't support it without extra coding.

You can see it here in the docs:

http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/appleapplications/Conceptual/SafariJSProgTopics/Articles/XHR.html

Comment: Thanks. I don't know how I ever would have figured this out. This is what happened to me using go-rest-json for golang. I had to "OPTIONS" to my allowed methods. Hopefully those keywords help someone else find it. :)